# Best practices with reading and operating on fortran ordered arrays with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm reading ascii and binary files that all specify 3 dimensional arrays in fortran order.  I want to perform some arbitrary manipulations on these arrays, then export them to the same ascii or binary format.

I'm confused on the best ways to deal with these arrays in my library.  My current design seems prone to error because I have to keep reshaping things from the default C order if any new array is created.

**Current design:**

I have a few functions that read these files and return numpy arrays.  The read functions all behave in a similar way and essentially read in the data and return something like:

`return array.reshape((i, j, k), order='F')`

The way I understand it, I'm returning a view for fortran order onto the original array.

My code assumes all the arrays are in fortran order.  This means any new operations that might create a new array I make sure to use `reshape` to convert it back to fortran order.

This seems very error-prone because I have to pay close attention to any operation that creates a new array and make sure to reshape it into fortran order since the default is usually C order.

I later might have to export these arrays to binary or ascii again and need to maintain the fortran ordering.  So, I use `numpy.nditer` to write each element out in the fortran order.

**Concerns:**

- The current approach seems very error-prone since I typically think in C order.  I'm afraid that I'll always be getting bitten by missing calls to `reshape` that forces things in C order.

  - I'd like to not have to worry about the ordering of the array elements except when reading the input files or writing the data to the output files.
- The current approach seems messy because the indexes can be interpreted different ways and things can get confusing.

  - When dealing with fortran arrays the tuple ordering for indexes is backwards, right?
  - So, `x[(1, 2, 3)]` for a fortran array means k = 1, j = 2, and i = 3 whereas `x[(1, 2, 3)]` for a C order array means k = 3, j = 2, i = 1 correct?
  - This means that me and users of my library must always think of indexes in (k, j, i) order, not what we are C/Python programmers typically think in, (i, j, k).

**Question:**

Is there a best practice for doing this type of thing?  In an ideal world I'd like to read in the fortran ordered arrays, then forget about ordering until I export to a file.  However, I'm afraid I'll keep misinterpreting the indexes, etc.

I've read through the only numpy documentation on this that I can find, http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/internals.html#multidimensional-array-indexing-order-issues.  However, the concept still seems as clear as mud to me.  Maybe I just need a different explanation of the numpy docs, http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/internals.html#multidimensional-array-indexing-order-issues.

Comment: You're over-thinking it. I'll elaborate in a bit, but you basically only need to worry about C vs F ordering when reading from or writing to disk. (Hint: to write, use `x.ravel(order='F').tofile(...)`) Numpy abstracts away the rest. Unless you're passing things back and forth to lower-level functions, there's no need to be careful about C vs F ordering on the python side.  From the python side, you'll index the array as `x[i,j,k]` regardless (unless you've read it in incorrectly).

Comment: @JoeKington Don't I have to worry about the order of the array when trying to index it though?  For example, if I want to get the element for i = 0, j = 2, k = 10 then I should use (0, 2, 10) for a C ordered array and (10, 2, 0) for a Fortran ordered array?  Thus, I need to specify to users of the library what is returned from the functions that read the data into numpy arrays, right?  I'm trying to keep all the arrays ordered the same way so users can NOT think about this and always use (i, j, k) or (k, j, i). This way all arrays are consistent.

Comment: Nope! You'll index it as `[0,2,10]` in python regardless. Numpy abstracts away the C vs. Fortran ordering in memory.  If you can't do that, it's because you didn't read the array in correctly (i.e. you read it in as if were C-ordered).  The simplest way to fix it is to do `x = x.T`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it may be a bit until I'm able to post a full answer (I really shouldn't be goofing off on SO at work, anyway.)  Hopefully someone beats me to it in the mean time!

Comment: @JoeKington No worries, I'd love to read a full answer.  I'm still over-thinking it.  So, even for fortran ordered arrays the index order is still (i, j, k)?

Comment: On the python side, yes. If you're having to use reversed indices, it's because you treated the array as C-ordered when you read it in and initially reshaped it.  If the array is fortran ordered on disk, then you'd do `np.fromfile('blah', dtype=whatever).reshape(nx,ny,nz, order='F')` to read it in and to write it back to disk, you'd do `data.ravel(order='F').tofile(blah)`.  (All of that assumes you're writing raw binary arrays to disk, but the same idea holds for ascii.)  If you do that correctly, you'll index it the same way on the python side as if it were C ordered.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Numpy abstracts away the difference between Fortran ordering and C-ordering at the python level. (In fact, you can even have other orderings for >2d arrays with numpy. They're all treated the same at the python level.)

The only time you'll need to worry about C vs F ordering is when you're reading/writing to disk or passing the array to lower-level functions.

### A Simple Example

As an example, let's make a simple 3D array in both C order and Fortran order:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: c_order = np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3)

In [3]: f_order = c_order.copy(order='F')

In [4]: c_order
Out[4]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]]])

In [5]: f_order
Out[5]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]]])
```

Notice that they both look identical (they are at the level we're interacting with them).  How can you tell that they're in different orderings?  First off, let's take a look at the flags (pay attention to `C_CONTIGUOUS` vs `F_CONTIGUOUS`):

```
In [6]: c_order.flags
Out[6]: 
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False

In [7]: f_order.flags
Out[7]: 
  C_CONTIGUOUS : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

And if you don't trust the flags, you can effectively view the memory order by looking at `arr.ravel(order='K')`.  The `order='K'` is important.  Otherwise, when you call `arr.ravel()` the output will be in C-order *regardless of the memory layout of the array*. `order='K'` uses the memory layout.

```
In [8]: c_order.ravel(order='K')
Out[8]: 
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26])

In [9]: f_order.ravel(order='K')
Out[9]: 
array([ 0,  9, 18,  3, 12, 21,  6, 15, 24,  1, 10, 19,  4, 13, 22,  7, 16,
       25,  2, 11, 20,  5, 14, 23,  8, 17, 26])
```

The difference is actually represented (and stored) in the `strides` of the array. Notice that `c_order`'s strides are `(72, 24, 8)`, while `f_order`'s strides are `(8, 24, 72)`.

Just to prove that the indexing works the same way:

```
In [10]: c_order[0,1,2]
Out[10]: 5

In [11]: f_order[0,1,2]
Out[11]: 5
```

### Reading and Writing

The main place where you'll run into problems with this is when you're reading from or writing to disk. Many file formats expect a particular ordering.  I'm guessing that you're working with seismic data formats, and most of them (e.g. Geoprobe .vol's, and I think Petrel's volume format as well) essentially write a binary header and then a Fortran-ordered 3D array to disk.

With that in mind, I'll use a small seismic cube (snippet of some data from my dissertation) as an example.

Both of these are binary arrays of `uint8`s with a shape of 50x100x198.  One is in C-order, while the other is in Fortran-order. [c_order.dat](http://www.geology.wisc.edu/~jkington/c_order.dat) [f_order.dat](http://www.geology.wisc.edu/~jkington/f_order.dat)

To read them in:

```
import numpy as np
shape = (50, 100, 198)

c_order = np.fromfile('c_order.dat', dtype=np.uint8).reshape(shape)
f_order = np.fromfile('f_order.dat', dtype=np.uint8).reshape(shape, order='F')

assert np.all(c_order == f_order)
```

Notice that the only difference is specifying the memory layout to `reshape`.  The memory layout of the two arrays is still different (reshape doesn't make a copy), but they're treated identically at the python level.

Just to prove that the files really are written in a different order:

```
In [1]: np.fromfile('c_order.dat', dtype=np.uint8)[:10]
Out[1]: array([132, 142, 107, 204,  37,  37, 217,  37,  82,  60], dtype=uint8)

In [2]: np.fromfile('f_order.dat', dtype=np.uint8)[:10]
Out[2]: array([132, 129, 140, 138, 110,  88, 110, 124, 142, 139], dtype=uint8)
```

Let's visualize the result:

```
def plot(data):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=3)
    for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
        slices = [slice(None), slice(None), slice(None)]
        slices[i] = data.shape[i] // 2
        ax.imshow(data[tuple(slices)].T, cmap='gray_r')
    return fig

plot(c_order).suptitle('C-ordered array')
plot(f_order).suptitle('F-ordered array')
plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]

Notice that we indexed them the same way, and they're displayed identically.

### Common Mistakes with IO

First off, let's try reading in the Fortran-ordered file as if it were C-ordered and then take a look at the result (using the `plot` function above):

```
wrong_order = np.fromfile('f_order.dat', dtype=np.uint8).reshape(shape)
plot(wrong_order)
```

[image]

Not so good!

You mentioned that you're having to use "reversed" indicies.  This is probably because you fixed what happened in the figure above by doing something like (note the reversed shape!):

```
c_order = np.fromfile('c_order.dat', dtype=np.uint8).reshape([50,100,198])
rev_f_order = np.fromfile('f_order.dat', dtype=np.uint8).reshape([198,100,50])
```

Let's visualize what happens:

```
plot(c_order).suptitle('C-ordered array')
plot(rev_f_order).suptitle('Incorrectly read Fortran-ordered array')
```

[image]
[image]

Note that the image on the far right (the timeslice) of the first plot matches a transposed version of the image on the far left of the second.

Similarly, `print rev_f_order[1,2,3]` and `print c_order[3,2,1]` both yield `140`, while indexing them the same way gives a different result.

Basically, this is where your reversed indices come from.  Numpy thinks it's a C-ordered array *with a different shape*.  Notice if we look at the flags, they're both C-contiguous in memory:

```
In [24]: rev_f_order.flags
Out[24]: 
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False

In [25]: c_order.flags
Out[25]: 
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

This is because a fortran-ordered array is equivalent to a C-ordered array *with the reverse shape*.

### Writing to Disk in Fortran-Order

There's an additional wrinkle when writing a numpy array to disk in Fortran-order.

Unless you specify otherwise, the array *will be written in C-order regardless* of its memory-layout! (There's a clear note about this in the documentation for `ndarray.tofile`, but it's a common gotcha. The opposite behavior would be incorrect, though, i.m.o.)

Therefore, regardless of the memory layout of an array, to write it to disk in Fortran order, you need to do:

```
arr.ravel(order='F').tofile('output.dat')
```

If you're writing it as ascii, the same applies.  Use `ravel(order='F')` and then write out the 1-dimensional result.

Comment: Great answer.  Really appreciate it!  I think I was mostly confused by looking at something like this: https://gist.github.com/durden/9548281 The printing is different because numpy is probably using nditer or something under the hood to print in the 'natural' order.  I'm confused a bit though because you're fixed example when creating the fortran order with copy() didn't suffer from this.

Comment: The reason for that is that the `order` kwarg to `reshape` tells numpy what order it should assume the underlying array is in (basically, `order` should only really be used for 1D inputs).  So `np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3, order='F')` assumes the 1D input is in Fortran order. If you take the same 1D sequence and interpret it two different ways, you'll get two different arrays. `copy(order='F')`, on the other hand, makes a copy of the array (same shape and content) with the memory-layout in Fortran-order. Hopefully that make sense, anyway. Glad to help, at any rate!

Comment: That makes sense. I think that was what I've been missing this whole time!

Comment: BTW I owe you a beer, especially since we're both in Houston and members of PyHou. Have we met before?

Comment: I don't know if we've met, but we've probably at least been in the same room, at any rate. Feel free to drop me a line sometime (my.name@gmail should work, or my github username @gmail. Both go to the same place.)  I'm not sure if I'll be at the PyHou meeting next week or not, but we should definitely grab a beer sometime, regardless!